# dependency injection: conditional

Tags: spring, grails

This is an extremely simplified example of something I'm already doing in Grails:

```
// this can be a service or normal class
public abstract class Person {
    public final String introduceSelf() {
        return "Hi, I'm " + getFullName()
    }

    protected abstract String getFullName()
}

// Service
class AlexService extends Person {
    protected String getFullName() {
        return "Alex Goodman"
    }
}

// Service
class BobService extends Person {
    protected String getFullName() {
        return "Bob Goodman"
    }
}

// Service
class CarlService extends Person {
    protected String getFullName() {
        return "Carl Goodman"
    }
}

// Controller
class IntroduceController {
    def alex
    def bob
    def carl

    def index() {
        if(params.person == "a")
            render alex.introduceSelf()
        if(params.person == "b")
            render bob.introduceSelf()
        if(params.person == "c")
            render carl.introduceSelf()
    }
}
```

I'm looking for more object oriented way of doing it, something like:

```
// Controller
class IntroduceController {
    def person

    def index() {
        // inject a proper person in a more object oriented way

        render person.introduceSelf()
    }
}
```

Can you suggest how to achieve this in a more object-oriented/dynamic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `person` bean definition in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` file. For example:

```
beans = {
    person(BobService)
}
```

For more information, check this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdslAdditional

Comment: Is bean a good idea for simply holding a single class, will that be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
class IntroduceController {

  def grailsApplication

  def index() {
    def person = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean( params.person )
    person.doSomething()
  }

}
```

You must make sure, that your services' names correspond to `params.person` value, `params.person = 'bob'` would work, `params.person = 'b'` would not

Comment: Is bean a good idea for simply holding a single class, will that be efficient?